# Find screen position of a form embedded in a form, embedded in a form,

Tags: forms, delphi, recursion, position, delphi-xe

I find myself in a tricky situation here, I have an application that has a form embedded in a form, embedded in a form, embedded in a form... (you got the picture).

I'm trying to find the middle of one of the forms (that was easy (`Self.Width div 2`) and (`Self.Height div 2`), right). Then the position relative to the screen (that was easy as well `(Self.Width div 2) + Self.Left` and `(Self.Height div 2) + Self.Top)`.

The problem is that this form is embedded in another form so I got 
`(Self.Width div 2) + Self.Left + Self.Parent.Left`
and 
`(Self.Height div 2) + Self.Top + Self.Parent.Top`

The problem is that I have 6 to 8 forms embedded in one another. I'm thinking a recursive call; the problem is that not all objects are forms, they are a mix of forms, tabs, panel, etc.

What would be an elegant way to solve it?

Comment: I don't think I understanf your question. If Form A is ***embedded*** in Form B, why would you want to position Form A relative to the screen? Surely that would just create a risk that you place Form A in some position obscured from view?

Comment: Lets say form A is at 100,100, Form B is at 50,50 (relative to form A) so form B is at 150,150, then lets say form C is at 0,100 and the size is 200,600. So the absolute position of form C is 150,250 and the center of this form is 250, 550. Does it make more sense? Sorry I should had put the example before.

Comment: Aaah, now I get it. I missed the bit about wanting to **find** the position of the form earlier. I've taken the liberty of disambiguating the title (along with other minor edits). When you implement the function in your own code, I strongly advise you prefix an appropriate verb, such as `Find` or `Get`. Also, since any control can have a position, you might want to generalise the solution offered by HeartWave. E.g. `FindCentreAsScreenCoords(AControl: TControl)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about this one:

```
FUNCTION CenterOfFormAsScreenCoords(F : TForm) : TPoint;
  BEGIN
    Result:=F.ClientToScreen(Point(0,0));
    Result:=Point(Result.Left+F.Width DIV 2,Result.Top+F.Height DIV 2)
  END;
```

or a combined version, as suggested by  Remy Lebeau:

```
FUNCTION CenterOfFormAsScreenCoords(F : TForm) : TPoint;
  BEGIN
    Result:=F.ClientToScreen(Point(F.Width DIV 2,F.Height DIV 2))
  END;
```

and a more general version (as suggested by Craig Young):

```
FUNCTION GetCenterOfControlAsScreenCoords(C : TControl) : TPoint;
  BEGIN
    Result:=C.ClientToScreen(Point(C.Width DIV 2,C.Height DIV 2))
  END;
```

or as a CLASS HELPER:

```
TYPE
  TControlHelper = CLASS HELPER FOR TControl
                     FUNCTION CenterAsScreenCoords : TPoint;
                   END;

FUNCTION TControlHelper.CenterAsScreenCoords : TPoint;
  BEGIN
    Result:=ClientToScreen(Point(Width DIV 2,Height DIV 2))
  END;
```

Comment: You can simplify that by passing the Form's center coordinates directly to `ClientToScreen()`:  `Result := F.ClientToScreen(Point(F.Width div 2, F.Height div 2));`